# libcap.so.2 missing while updating to GLIBC_2.29

Tags: c, ubuntu, glibc

I had problem with GLIBC version while executing an `exe` file compiled in `c`.

```
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6: version 'GLIBC_2.29' not found
```

I found that I was using `GLIBC_2.27`. I updated to `GLIBC_2.29` as mentioned the [post](https://www.jertype.com/posts/upgrading-glibc/) 
Once I installed `GLIBC_2.29`, I set the library path using `patchelf` command like below,

```
patchelf --set-interpreter /path/to/newglibc/ld-linux.so.2 --set-rpath /path/to/newglibc/ myapp
```

Now I got a new error,

```
error while loading shared libraries: libcap.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

On checking for the file `libcap.so.2` mentioned, I could see it is in the `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/` path.

I am not sure how to set path for the libcap as I already set path to the glib.

Did I set the path in the wrong manner?. Is there anything I missed during the path setup in the above step?

> **NOTE : My Operating system is Ubuntu 18.01**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am not sure how to set path for the libcap as I already set path to the glib.

You can set multiple `RUNPATH`s like so:

```
patchelf --set-interpreter /path/to/newglibc/ld-linux.so.2 \
  --set-rpath /path/to/newglibc:/lib myapp
```